# Jsoup and for loop nosuchelementexception

Tags: java, runtime-error, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to gather data on Yahoo Finance by constantly changing URL string.
Here is my code to make more sense:

```java
    public static void gatherLoop() throws NoSuchElementException, IOException {
        for (var i = 1; i < 99; i++) {
            BufferedReader gatherStocks = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stockNames.txt"));
            Stream<String> load = Files.lines(Paths.get("stockNames.txt"));
            String loadString = load.skip(i).findFirst().get();
            String glURL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+loadString+"?p="+loadString+"&.tsrc=fin-srch";

            if (glURL.equals("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/?p=&.tsrc=fin-srch")) {
                gatherStocks.close();
                System.out.println("Loaded Stocks");
                System.out.println("If Their Is No Stocks Popping Up, You Have No Saved Stocks");
            }
            else {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(glURL).get();
                Elements contentA = doc.getElementsByClass("D(ib) Fz(18px)");
                System.out.println("|------------------------------------------------|");
                for(Element a : contentA) {
                    System.out.println("| " + i + ". Name: " + a.text());
                    gatherStocks.readLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I run the code I get a runtime error in the compiler:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:143)
        at StockAnalysis.saves.gatherLoop(saves.java:32)
        at StockAnalysis.saves.gatherSavedStocks(saves.java:25)
        at StockAnalysis.Home.main(Home.java:27)
```

The first thing I tried was just doing `i++` and running the `void` again but that would reset `i` back to zero. Then I tried just reading `loadstring` string.

Comment: How many lines are there in file `stockNames.txt`? Are there less than 99 lines in the file? From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#get()): _Throws: NoSuchElementException - if no value is present_ `String loadString = load.skip(i).findFirst().get();` ___findFirst___ is returning an empty `Optional`.

Comment: In this situation, it can vary up to 99 because you can add more lines

Comment: Let's say the file has 20 lines. In your `for` loop, once `i` is greater than 20, you will skip all the lines in the file, so `findFirst` will return an "empty" `Optional`. By the way, the documentation states that the `Stream` should be closed (if I remember correctly) - something that you are not doing.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.
Here is my *stocknames.txt* file:

```
RIVN
SNAP
NVOS
AMAM
TRKA
BBIO
SAVE
UNCY
AAPL
NTNX
SOFI
GLPH
GBTC
```

Each line is the stock [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_symbol).
The below code reads each line of file *stocknames.txt* and, for each line read, calls method `showName` which outputs the name associated with the given symbol. I believe that is what you are trying to do.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Extractor {
    private static final String TEMPLATE = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s?p=%s&.tsrc=fin-srch";

    public static void showName(String name) throws IOException {
        String url = String.format(TEMPLATE, name, name);
        Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url);
        Document doc = conn.get(); // throws java.io.IOException
        Elements contentA = doc.getElementsByClass("D(ib) Fz(18px)");
        for (Element a : contentA) {
            System.out.println(a.text());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner gatherStocks = new Scanner(new File("stocknames.txt"))) {
            while (gatherStocks.hasNextLine()) {
                String name = gatherStocks.nextLine();
                showName(name);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
Rivian Automotive, Inc. (RIVN)
Snap Inc. (SNAP)
Novo Integrated Sciences, Inc. (NVOS)
Ambrx Biopharma Inc. (AMAM)
Troika Media Group, Inc. (TRKA)
BridgeBio Pharma, Inc. (BBIO)
Spirit Airlines, Inc. (SAVE)
Unicycive Therapeutics, Inc. (UNCY)
Apple Inc. (AAPL)
Nutanix, Inc. (NTNX)
SoFi Technologies, Inc. (SOFI)
Grayscale Bitcoin Trust (BTC) (GBTC)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this method later.

Comment: Is there a way to not have the main method in this, because my main method is a home screen.

Comment: @Kit the body of method `main` can be put in any method you like.

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new to java.